# JS: Image not showing

Tags: javascript, image

I want to show a simple ajax loading animation during the timeout period. The image gets hidden on `window.load` as it should, but when I click on an image and use the `onclick= call`, the image is not showing.

This is my `showImage()` method

```
    function showImage(){
        document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display="normal";
}
```

And this is my div

```
<div id='welcome' style="display:none">
 Click to continue.<br /><br /><!--Viral Text-->
 <img src="like1.png" width="100" height="44" onclick="likeToUnlock(); showImage();" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <img id="loadingImage" src="ajax.gif" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the style="display:none" attribute on the img is the issue...

Answer (score 0):

There is no `display:normal`, you want `display:inline-block`, since inline-block is the default display property of a `img`.

```
document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.display="inline-block";
```

Also your entire `div` containing the image is not displayed so to show the image its ancestor elements must also be displayed.

Comment: Div is displayed by javascript, it shows. Just the image doesn't show up. I'll try inline-block and post the result

Comment: Sure

`function likeToUnlock() {
 window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com','popUpWindow','height=200,width=600,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no');
 setCookie('ok', true);
 interval = setInterval(undimPage ,5000);
}`